# Escaping "$" using gsub()

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to replace a preceding "`$`" in a string with "`\$`". For example, "`$5 special`" should become "`\$5 special`".

I've tried:

```
"$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, "\$") => "$5 special"  
"$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, "\\$") => "\\$5 special"  
"$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, "\\\$") => "\\$5 special"
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example,

```
"$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, "\\$")
```

Should do it. The reason why you see two slashes in your output, is due to Ruby escaping the slash in the string for printing it as a literal. If you print it to standard out, you'd see it's what you expect:

```
irb(main):009:0> a = "$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, "\\$")
=> "\\$5 special"
irb(main):011:0> print a
\$5 special=> nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use single quotes for the substitution:

```
>> "$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, '\$') #=> "\\$5 special"
>> puts "$5 special".gsub(/^\$/, '\$') #=> nil
\$5 special
```

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` can accept strings as well, in which case you don't have to escape the `$`:

```
"$5 special".gsub("$", '\$') #=> "\\$5 special"
```